# How to recover the secret keys of environments safely using OpenSSL?

Tags: github, openssl, environment-variables, github-actions

I don't understand much about openSSL and I saw this code in yaml by google:

But the person did not explain in detail how to use it, so the following questions remained:

```
# Assumption:
# You've created the following GitHub secrets in your repository:
# MY_CLIENT_SECRET - encrypt/decrypt with openssl - useful for public and public repositories
# MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD - used to protect secrets
# MY_OPENSSL_ITER - Use a number of iterations on the password to derive the encryption key.
#                   High values increase the time required to brute-force the resulting file.
#                   This option enables the use of PBKDF2 algorithm to derive the key.

name: Recovering Secret Keys
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  openssl:
    name: Recover With OpenSSL
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - env:
          MY_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_CLIENT_SECRET }}
          MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD }}
          MY_OPENSSL_ITER: ${{ secrets.MY_OPENSSL_ITER }}
        run: |
          echo "MY_CLIENT_SECRET (***)     = ${MY_CLIENT_SECRET}"
          echo "MY_CLIENT_SECRET (openssl) = $(echo "${MY_CLIENT_SECRET}" | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -pbkdf2 -iter ${MY_OPENSSL_ITER} -k "${MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD}")"
          echo "Copy the above value, and then execute locally:"
          echo "echo PASTE_HERE | openssl base64 -d | openssl enc -d -pbkdf2 -iter \$MY_OPENSSL_ITER -aes-256-cbc -k \$MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD"
```

I have a personal project where the code will be public, I need to get the secret envs and create a file with them, but only certain people can do it, to be able to use it in the project.

1. How do I block this so that certain people can view and generate the .envs files with the secret keys?
2. How do I decrypt and create secret env files?
3. What is it and how to get the `MY_CLIENT_SECRET`, `MY_OPENSSL_PASSWORD`, `MY_OPENSSL_ITER`?

Comment: The secrets don't live in a file in your repo, that would be visible to anyone. Instead, you put them in your GitHub account for that repo. Open the repo's settings, scan in the left column for Secrets, and add Action Secrets for the three variables you need. That's accessible to the workflows, but cannot be displayed or seen by anyone but you. In fact, I think GitHub won't even show them to you, it'll only let you update their value.

Comment: The manual is long, but helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets